# Ordering in SQL based on 2 fields

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a way to compare players, basically - hiscores.
A problem I have is this: I need to order based on two variables. Currently I'm ordering by the total level, and if there's two or more players with the same total level, I want to order it by their total xp.

Example:
I have the query

```
SELECT * FROM overall ORDER BY `total_level` DESC LIMIT 30
```

And it returns this
http://gyazo.com/73698236977bbe2b94f8079d769b81a5.png

This is not good because since they have the same Total Level, I need it to order by their total xp to show that one member is better than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about giving both columns to order directly in your query?

```
SELECT * FROM overall ORDER BY `total_level` DESC, `total_xp` DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: @Tom i'm glad it solved, don't forget to accept answer if it was correct for people in the future with similar problems